# Case With Aggregate Function in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I've a table with user's monthly attendance details that has a overtime column. So the table has the below structure and sample data:

```
Date      - Id   - Dept - OT - Status
12/1/2019 - 1001 - HR   - 2  - P
12/2/2019 - 1001 - HR   - 4  - P 
12/1/2019 - 1002 - IT   - 2  - P
12/2/2019 - 1002 - IT   - 4  - P
```

I omitted the in and out time here as that isn't the primary issue here. See in the above, the overtime are calculated for each user. So it's easy to calculate the total overtime details of a user or department as follows:

```
SELECT DEPT, SUM(OT) TOTAL FROM ATTENDANCE m WHERE M.DATE >= '01-DEC-2019' AND M.DATE <= '10-DEC-2019'
GROUP BY M.DEPT
```

My requirement is to get the weekly or 7 days overtime details of a department with a specific date range as well the overtime range will be say 40. As an example: For a department, date range 1 to 7 of December, 2019 and the total overtime will be up to 40 hours or between 41 to 50 hours. So I tried the following:

```
SELECT DEPT, SUM(OT) TOTAL FROM ATTENDANCE m WHERE M.DATE >= '01-DEC-2019' AND M.DATE <= '07-DEC-2019'
HAVING SUM(OT) <= 40 GROUP BY M.DEPT
```

Or:

```
SELECT DEPT, SUM(OT) TOTAL FROM ATTENDANCE m WHERE M.DATE >= '01-DEC-2019' AND M.DATE <= '07-DEC-2019'
HAVING SUM(OT) BETWEEN 41 AND 50 GROUP BY M.DEPT
```

Or:

```
SELECT DEPT, SUM(OT) TOTAL FROM ATTENDANCE m WHERE M.DATE >= '01-DEC-2019' AND M.DATE <= '07-DEC-2019'
HAVING SUM(OT) > 50 GROUP BY M.DEPT
```

But the last query seems to return weird output and seems like it returns data that I retrieved with the first query. These are separate queries that I tired but am thinking if I can manage it to work with a `CASE WHEN` with all the ranges given above as follows using a sub-query:

```
CASE WHEN M.DATE >= '01-DEC-2019' AND M.DATE <= '07-DEC-2019'
AND SUM(OT) <= 40 THEN SUM(OT) 
CASE WHEN M.DATE >= '01-DEC-2019' AND M.DATE <= '07-DEC-2019'
AND SUM(OT) BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN SUM(OT)
```

I am not sure if aggregate function could be used withing a `CASE WHEN` statement or any way that I can use the above to run several ranges within the query? Thanks.

Comment: Without reading any further, try this first... Do not compare dates to strings. Instead of `'01-DEC-2019'` write `to_date('01-DEC-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY')` (and similar everywhere else) and see if the query works as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate all values using `CASE`. For example:

```
select 
  dept, 
  sum(ot) as total,
  case when sum(ot) <= 40 then 'g1'
       when sum(ot) > 40 and sum(ot) <= 50 then 'g2'
       else 'g3' end as g
from attendance
where between to_date('2019-12-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
          and to_date('2019-12-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
group by dept
```

Comment: @mathguy OK, was not part of the point, but fixed the code to work in Oracle. Additionally used ISO date format, removed the English format.

Comment: "Not part of the point" is true, but still - if we teach someone how to do algebra, we don't allow them to divide by zero even if that's not what they asked about. Anyway, you fixed it, so I removed the downvote. That's how it's supposed to work. I would not have objected, but both answers (both using strings for dates) were posted **after** I had already pointed this out to the OP in a comment under his question.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more explicit in what you desired output is? It seems like there are two results you are looking for (departments that have *up-to* 40 hours of overtime, and departments that have *over* 40 hours of overtime in a given date range)?

Looking at your last query:

```sql
CASE WHEN M.DATE >= '01-DEC-2019' AND M.DATE <= '07-DEC-2019'
AND SUM(OT) <= 40 THEN SUM(OT) 
CASE WHEN M.DATE >= '01-DEC-2019' AND M.DATE <= '07-DEC-2019'
AND SUM(OT) BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN SUM(OT)
```

Given that the date range applied is the same, can you just move this to the `WHERE` clause? You could then use a subquery or some other approach to group departments by how much overtime has been used (something like this):

```sql
SELECT
    Dept
    , CASE
        WHEN TotalOvertime <= 40 THEN 'something'
        WHEN (TotalOvertime > 40 AND <= 50) THEN 'something_else'
        ELSE 'exception'
    END AS OvertimeCaseStatement
FROM (
SELECT Dept
    , SUM(OT) AS TotalOvertime
FROM Attendance
WHERE Date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-DEC-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('07-DEC-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
GROUP BY Dept
)
;
```

I also removed the `BETWEEN` operator in your int comparison, as I think using the logical operators is a *bit* more clear (`BETWEEN` is an inclusive operator), and added some bad names like `something`, `something_else`, etc. that you can change for more descriptive names.

Please let me know if I am addressing your actual question, and if there are new errors/problems with this approach!

Also FWIW, if you `Date` column is a date and not a string, it may help to `CAST` your parameters (`'01-DEC-2019'`, etc.) to be a date type. Hope this helps!

***Edited*:** added date casting with `TO_DATE()` based on a good call-out from @mathguy (I am assuming `Date` is already a datetype col).

Comment: In here, can I write this -  `WHEN TotalOvertime <= 40 THEN 'something' to this -  WHEN TotalOvertime <= 40 THEN TotalOvertime or SUM(OT)`?

Comment: I do not know that I totally understand what you are asking--are you hoping to have an aggregate function be the result of a `CASE` statement?

Depending on your desired output for this query as a whole, there may be a simpler way to get your desired result